# how would to count elements in keyed json in jquery

Tags: javascript, json

I wan't to find the number of records in a keyed json object in jquery.

For example if I have an indexed object as follows

```
var json = [{"key1":{"value":"33"},"key2":{"value":"36 "},"key3":{"value":"38"},"key4":{"value":"41"}}]
```

How could I get a count of the number of records? (their are 4 records)

Comment: json.length returns undefined

Comment: the format of json variable is invalid

Comment: I have just corrected that

Comment: Check this `Object.keys(json[0]).length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the `array` of all the `keys` in object.

In your case, `json` array contains an object. So, you can use `json[0]` to get the `object` from array and then use `Object.keys()` on it.

```
Object.keys(json[0]).length
```

```js
var json = [{
  "key1": {
    "value": "33"
  },
  "key2": {
    "value": "36 "
  },
  "key3": {
    "value": "38"
  },
  "key4": {
    "value": "41"
  }
}];

document.write(Object.keys(json[0]).length);
```